# Mockito Null Pointer Exception when initializing using @RunWith annotation when mocking

Tags: spring, nullpointerexception, mocking, annotations, mockito

I'm using Mockito to create mock beans, and for some reason, when I initialize a mock with @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class), I get an error when I call a method from the mocked class. However, if I initialize using @BeforeEach, it works fine. to be more specific:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class Test {        
    
    @Mock   
    Bean mockBean;
    
    @Test   
    void testGet() {         
    Mockito.when(mockBean.method()).thenReturn(2);      
    assertEquals(2, mockBean.method());     
    }
```

The above causes a NullPointException error on the line `Mockito.when(mockBean.method()).thenReturn(2);`

H**owever, if I do the below:

```
class Test {
    
    @Mock
    Bean mockBean;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void testGet() {
        Mockito.when(mockBean.method()).thenReturn(2);
        assertEquals(2, mockBean.method());
    }
```

the test runs just fine. I was under the impression that the two should work the same. I'd appreciate it if anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong or misunderstanding.

Comment: You might be mixing JUnit4 and 5. In 5 the class and tests don't have to `public` but the `@RunWIth` needs to be `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`. You would probably need a newer version of Mockito also.

Comment: Could you add your imports?